# A system of $4$ linear equations in $3$ unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am a having hard times solving this. Any help will be appreciated.

$0.4a +0.8b+0.1c=a$,
$0.3a+0.2b+0.3c=b$,
$0.3a+0.6c=c$,

and we have 1 more info

$a+b+c=1$

Comment: Have you tried putting it into matrix form?

Comment: I tried making $0's$ under the main diagonal, but it got very complicated.

Comment: From last equation $0.3a+0.6c=c$ we get $c=\frac{3}{4}a$

Comment: You can ignore one of the equations from the first three equations.  One equation is redundant.  For example, you can obtain the second from the first and the third as follows: $$0.3a+0.2b+0.3c=(a+b+c)-(0.4a+0.8b+0.1c)-(0.3a+0.6c)=(a+b+c)-a-c=b.$$  So, you may only use the first, third, and forth equations to solve the system, and note Qurultay's comment.

Comment: Yes I get it , but it is hard to see that one equation is redundant.

Comment: From eq(3), we get $a=\frac{0.4}{0.3}c$ and from eq(4), we get $b=1-\frac{0.7}{0.3}c$. Now merely substitute them in eq(1) or eq(2).

Answer (score 2):

Your first three equations can be written as a matrix equation.

Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0.4 & 0.8 & 0.1 \\
0.3 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
0.3 & 0 & 0.6
\end{bmatrix}, 
\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}.
$$

You want to find a $\mathbf{v}$ such that $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$. This should remind you of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, where in your case, the eigenvector you're looking for has a corresponding eigenvalue $1$.

Once you have found a $\mathbf{v}$ that solves this equation, you have to deal with your additional constraint, being that $a + b + c = 1$. This constraint shouldn't be hard to deal with, since for any eigenvector $\mathbf{u}$, the vector $c\mathbf{u}$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$, is also an eigenvector.

If you have limited knowledge of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, there is tons of material on this topic, e.g. https://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0601.pdf.